# unable to open include file 'io.mac' assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, ubuntu-12.04, nasm

I am using nasm assembler and 32 bit Ubuntu.When I try to execute a program,"unable to open include file 'io.mac' " error occurs.My compile commands :

```
nasm -f elf32 fact.asm
```

After I have searched this problem in some sites,I try :

```
nasm -f elf32 fact.asm -l fact.lst
```

However,error has not changed.Pls help.

Comment: Does the file `io.mac` exist, and do you have permissions to read it?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't got the file, this may be it:

http://www.scs.carleton.ca/sivarama/org_book/org_book_web/source_code.html

If you have the file, but it isn't in the current directory, the `-i` switch may help.

http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11/html/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1.16