# How do I print from register CL using PutInt

Tags: assembly, nasm

I want to add two 8 bit registers together and print the result. I would like to add register CL and CH. I populated ECX with -1275 and I want to see what the result will be if I subtract these two register, how do I do this?

This is what I wrote however I get an error on line 13 that says invalid combination of opcode and operands. Why cant I use PutInt to print from CL? What do I need to do?

```
%include "io.mac"
.STACK 100H 
.DATA

   msg4  db "The result is: ",0
   .CODE
        .STARTUP
    mov ECX,1111101100000101b


    PutStr msg4  ; print msg4 on the output
    add CL, CH   ; Add results
    PutInt CL   ; output int from register CL <-- line 13
    nwln
    done:                        
        .EXIT
```

Comment: `PutInt` is not x86 assembly instruction. It looks as some kind of macro. You have to check the documentation of the macros you are using, or show their code. It's impossible to answer this as is (edit the question with relevant code, if the `PutInt` macro is short enough with all the other used macros expanded). BTW, use rather debugger to check CPU state, it's very common to mess up debug output for beginners, then they reason about wrong numbers, while the actual state of CPU is different in reality.

Comment: Apparently it's a macro-package that goes with some book: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169375/unable-to-open-include-file-io-mac-assembly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PutInt doesn't take 8-bit operands. But you could use CX:

```
mov CH, 0 ; clear high-byte
PutInt CX
```

The high-byte is cleared by a simple mov operation, that's it.

Comment: Given they used _ECX_ as a register implies a 32-bit processor. They could also simply use `movzx cx, cl` to zero extend _CL_ into _CX_

Comment: When I add these together I get -1280. Why would this be?

Comment: @Rubiks Because `add CL, CH` takes the value in CH, adds it to CL storing result in just CL. It wom't alter the rest of the _CX_ register (including _CH_). So what was in CH remains in CH after the add.

Comment: CH should be 11111011. Since ECX is -1275 I am guessing it interprets this as -5? Then CL holds 00000101, so shouldn't the answer be 0?

Comment: @Rubiks binary 11111011+00000101 will equal 0 when adding two bytes together storing into a byte.. Thus _CL_ becomes zero after the addition. Since _CH_ remains unchanged you now have this in _CX_ = 1111101100000000 = -1280 decimal. And yes 11111011 as a 2s complement signed byte is -5. Adding 5 to minus -5 is 0 when dealing with signed values.